# Git: Revert to previous commit status

Tags: git, commit, reset

I'm confused. I want to go back to a previous commit that I identified in "git log".

But when I do "git checkout ", I don't get said commit. Nothing changes.
It tells me I'm in detached HEAD mode, but the files I want are not there.

What the eff am I doing wrong?

MrB

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`git reset --hard <commit>` From the manpage:

> Matches the working tree and index to that of the tree being switched to. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since  are lost.

`git checkout` is for switching your working directory to a different branch or commit. This does not move the `HEAD` there.

Comment: Again, `reset` is for resetting your index and working directory to a previous state. `checkout` is for checking out a new or different branch. Once you get used to it it's not so confusing. =)

Comment: Check out http://www.gitready.com/ and http://learn.github.com/p/intro.html for cool tutorials, and then http://gitref.org for a reference when you're ready.

Comment: Actually, you can use `git checkout` for changing your working tree to the state of any commit - if you're not checking out a branch, it'll detach HEAD, but it all works fine.  (For example, that's typically what you do when trying to find the last good commit when starting a `git bisect`.)

Comment: I suspect `reset` just reinstates the old state on top of the recent (and unwanted) commits… Is there a way to do that in terms of moving the HEAD/current branch pointer ?

Comment: @Damien Pollet: No, `git reset` is the porcelain command that changes HEAD (typically the current branch) to point to the given commit, and has various options (`--soft`, `--hard`, `--mixed`) that determine what happens to working tree and index when that happens...

Answer (score 11):

**DO NOT git reset -hard it is PERMANENT!**

Please use

```
git stash -u
```

instead! If you have a piece of work in there that you zapped by accident, you can still get it back. This never gets pushed to your remote unless you choose to do so by making a branch out of it and pushing it up.

Also, you are on the right track that you can use `git checkout` to accomplish the same thing. The syntax is

```
git checkout HEAD -- .
```

But it has the same problem as `git reset --hard`. Stick with stash and you will save losing your hair in the future.

**Longer answer**

The above solutions revert all your changes. However, you asked how to get rid of some of the changes. I'll add this for completeness.

To do this, you can

```
git add file1 file2 file3
git stash save --patch
```

You will now be prompted for what exactly you want to make dissappear... down to what ever level of granularity. So you can safely "reject" only a few changes to a single file if you choose to do so.

Comment: What if I want it to be permanent? I sometimes begin to make changes that I never want to see again.

Comment: "DO NOT git reset -hard it is PERMANENT!" no its not,  what about `git reflog` ?

Comment: Yes, please note this answer is incorrect...`git reset  --hard` only permanently changes uncommited code

Answer (score 0):

In git first you got your commit identifier and use that identifier you can revert your commit

```
git reset --hard 50c0369
git push -f
```